# dSYM symbols are being hidden after submitting bitcode-enabled build to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a very strange issue related to dSYMs which Apple generates on its' side when I upload a build to iTunes Connect with "enable bitcode" setting set to "yes": all debug symbols become hidden.

However, before uploading build to Apple my single dSYM file has only few of them, which gives me an idea, that they will become hidden on Apple's side as a result of build processing. I run following command in order to filter out all hidden entries from dSYMs:

```
dwarfdump *.dSYM | grep "hidden"
```

The build which I upload to iTunes Coonnect is "Release" one. Here are the relevant debug setting which I use when building:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've already filed a RADAR for this issue, but wanted to know whether I'm missing something obvious here or not.

Thank you!

Comment: Disabling bitcode helps to get non-hidden symbols back.

Answer (score 0):

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
>   you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
>   linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize
>   your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version
>   of your app to the store.
>
> Xcode hides symbols generated during build time by default, so they
>   are not readable by Apple. Only if you choose to include symbols when
>   uploading your app to iTunes Connect would the symbols be sent to
>   Apple. You must include symbols to receive crash reports from Apple.

Comment: Did you see the build/debug settings I've posted in my original question? Are there any settings that make symbols "hidden"? I didn't find any...

Answer (score 0):

To receive symbolicated crash logs for your applications (whether or not they include bitcode) you must check the "Include app symbols" checkbox presented during the submission process.
But, there are some issues regarding this.
Check the following links to see the solutions:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18646
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cdb5ba3791cfd7d312c2